# How can I load my Azure Map within a Jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, azure-maps

Trying to get my Azure map to display within a jumbotron with a bit of padding to the edges. So far cannot get it to stay within the Jumbotron's boundaries with a little bit of padding. Any ideas?

Script in head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function InitMap()
    {
        var map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
            style: 'satellite_road_labels',
            center: [-122.33, 47.6],
            zoom: 12,
            language: 'en-US',
            authOptions: {
                authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                subscriptionKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        });
   }
</script>
```

Loads with body:

```
<body onload="InitMap()">
```

Style sheet within page:

```
    <style>
        .mapContainer {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 290px;
            height: 600px;
        }



       #myMap {
         
         height: 100vh;
         width: 100vw;
       }

 

        .jumbotron {
            padding-top: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            color: inherit;
            background-color: #eee;
        }


    </style>
```

Map within second column where Jumbotron is:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container-md"> <div id="myMap"></div></div>
</div>
 
    </div>
```

Comment: Just as a test... Bootstrap has it's own padding facility (Spacing). You can hopefully add the padding without the need for extra CSS and then Bootstrap itself will take care of keeping everything measured and correctly orientated. So you could have padding on the Jumbotron like this `class="jumbotron p-*"` Where X is a number between 0 (no padding) and 5 (max padding). You can also use `px-*` for horizontal padding only or `py-*` for vertical padding. I might also remove the container so that it just meant dealing with the jumbotron div.

Comment: Hard to say. It's possible that the jumbotron div has no size when the map is being loaded, and thus the map canvas is 0 pixels wide/high. One thing to test in the console is get your map control instance and call the resize function. `map.resize()` this will force a recalculation of the map canvas size. If this shows the map, then this would verify the issue is that there is not space available for the map when its being loaded, so you can either set the dimensions in CSS ahead of time, or try calling the resize function in the maps "ready" event handler.